# Installing files via Composer via Command Line | "'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: command-line, windows-10

So I am attempting to install some files from Send Grid via Composer usind the CommandLine.

I am following a tutorial with the link here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEobqi3N7zw

The guy in the video has no problem using Composer via the Command Line in the Windows Command Prompt, but when I input the command `$ go_www`, my PC whines and stamps it's feet, giving me the following line:

```
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

In a nutshell, why?

**System Information:**
Windows 10 64x

I have looked at other posts on here, to no avail, I have tried opening the Command Line too as System Administrator, but to avail. I have tried restarting the system, to no avail, I can confirmed I have composer installed into the correct directory, to no avail .

Comment: "when I do this" - what does that mean? Can you share the command you are running?

Comment: What command did you try inputting? Is it a Git Bash shell or a normal Windows command prompt? I think it's fairly clear to see what's going on but we need extra info to fully diagnose your problem.

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry, all questions address in the post.

Comment: @chemicalchems sorry, all questions address in the post.

Comment: `$ go_www`  does not look like a command after all - how is this even related to Composer or SendGrid?

Comment: @NicoHaase because I'm trying to user Composer to obtain files via SendGrid, to begin with, I need to use the Command/Bash to retrieve the files from SendGrid.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Usually, Composer does not require the command `go_www`. Why not ask whoever provides that tutorial for clarification?

Comment: @nicohasse that's exactly what I have done Nico.

Answer (score 0):

`$` in a shell indicates the shell is not owned by a superuser, it is not part of the command. Try running `go_www`. Also, the video you linked seems to be using a bash shell, whereas you appear to be running a Windows command prompt from the error message you included in your question, which might be a problem too.

In any case, `go_www` is an alias the video author uses to quickly navigate to the folder of interest. Try manually navigating there using `cd`.

Comment: I have attempted to jus try running `go_www` and it's still the same result.

Comment: @SimplyTheMighty Edit added.

Comment: I have tried the command line `cd` it doesn't even acknowledge it.

Comment: @SimplyTheMighty I suggest before jumping into the deep end, you learn how to use a command prompt / command line interface first. There are many tutorials on Bash available, if that's the choice you're gonna make. If so, for Windows I would recommend installing Git Bash or Cygwin.

Comment: I agree with you. It's just that if I pay SendGrid to guide me through the process of deploying their product and it really should not be this hard. If I follow a set of instructions then I expect the product to do what it says it does, not to give me error after error after error after error after error. Sick to death of it is an understatement.